# jwplayer 5.5 + Fancybox + Iphone not playing issue

Tags: jwplayer

Here is the implementation and if you test on iPhone it doesn't works.
http://fldtrace.com/dev/yoogi/

This guy made it work somehow:
http://www.dr-ramadani.de/index.php

Can anyone point me to the right direction or if you can recommend other technique, so the video can be viewed on iPhones, I'd appreciate that.
Maybe a conditional for iPhones to load the video in quicktimes, instead of opening it the lightbox.

I tried on their forums but they pointed me to a "supported" lightbox that doesn't works either.

Comment: This seems to work for me. Did you fix it?